# How to do a linear regression with variables from a dataframe [Python]

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have two variables A and B in a dataframe. When i try this:

```py
x=df.['A']
y=df.['B']

M = LinearRegression()
M.fit(A,B)
```

I get the following error

```
Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[86.  0. 86. ...  0.  0.  0.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Although when i try to apply the reshape as suggested, i got a "'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'"

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change `x` to DataFrame rather than Series.

```py
x = df[['A']]
y = df['B']
```

Comment: I think that worked, whats the difference between dataframe and series?

Comment: @ViB row/column in DataFrame is a Series, DataFrame can be 2D array while Series is 1D.

Comment: @ViB Locating with list of label is to subset the DataFrame, here you can take `df[['A']]` as `x = df[['a', 'b', 'c']]` which mean you want to use feature a, b, c which is columns in DataFrame to predict target B.